# Sticky thead on page scroll and overflow-x not working

Tags: html, css

When I add CSS overflow-x: auto; then the stick which is added to the table th is not working. The mental leap for that is a tough one for me. Why isn't my `position: sticky;` working? I am trying to fix it another way but fails. What can I try next?

This is my current code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer_box5 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: #5ffc6c;
}

.table-fixed {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 2400px;
}

.table-fixed thead th {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    /*-- inline css in css section--*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; background: #ffd18d;"></div>
  <div class="outer_box5">
    <table class="table-fixed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Table Header 1</th>
          <th>Table Header 2</th>
          <th>Table Header 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; background: #ffd18d;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you want to stick you table header on top of the page while scrolling the page?

Comment: Please do not post rubbish to defeat the post quality filter - that just creates new work for volunteer editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table header IS sticky. It sticks to the top (at the same y pos) of the table regardless of how small/big the table is. It's the left position that isn't fixed, but you've added scrolling, so you're gonna want to see the table header 2 or 3 as appropriate on scrolling across.

To illustrate the point, I've shortened your outer box to 125px and added overflow-y:scroll, so you can see the effect. Scroll down and you will see the `th` stay in position while the data rolls up and down.

You may want to narrow the width of the box so that the down arrow is visible without having to scroll across.

Hope this clarifies things a bit for you

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer_box5 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  height:125px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background: #5ffc6c;
}

.table-fixed {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 2400px;
}

.table-fixed thead th {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    /*-- inline css in css section--*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; background: #ffd18d;"></div>
  <div class="outer_box5">
    <table class="table-fixed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Table Header 1</th>
          <th>Table Header 2</th>
          <th>Table Header 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; background: #ffd18d;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```